# libGDX game crashes on Android without any logs / errosrs

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, libgdx, crash

> This question was asked in the thematic community, but the answer was
>   not received. First, it is necessary to solve the problem. Secondly, I
>   think it will be useful to make cross-references so that people who
>   are faced with this problem can quickly find the answer. [Question in
>   the thematic community](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/156544/libgdx-game-crashes-on-android-without-any-logs-errosrs)

libGDX game crashes without any errors in the console on Android devices. It happens in different parts of the game at different screens at a different time. I don't see the reason. 
Game works well, without freezing. The game does not crash under resource-intensive operations like changing the screen, but already when the screen is loaded and the player plays for a while. The use of memory would probably be normal, based on the graphs of the use of RAM. The CPU is also not overloaded.
[image]
The strangest thing is that when a game crashes there are no errors displayed in the console.
The phone screen turns black for a while, then the system emits on the home screen.The phone also does not show error messages in the application, etc.
Also, sometimes after displaying the AdMob video, the game stops responding to the input, although the graphics continue to work, the animations are working.

At first, I thought it might be due to AdMob's incorrect implementation. But after the complete removal of AdMob from the project, the problem did not disappear.

What then can lead to such behaviour of the application?

Perhaps this is due to some error in `AssetManager`? I would like to note that I use a large number of textures (more then 170), packed in an atlas. All textures in atlas takes *4.31MB* disk space and all my assets takes *6.2MB.* All the resources I load during the initial loading of the game using `AssetManager`.

So, my **Res** class:

```
public class Res {

    public static final String LOCALE_BUNDLE_PATH = "i18n/locale";

    public static final String MAIN_ATLAS_PATH = "packs/main/MAIN.atlas";
    public static final String MUSIC_M3_THEME_PATH = "music/atc_m3_theme.mp3";
    public static final String KICK_SOUND_PATH = "music/atc_kick.mp3";
    public static final String FADEIN_SOUND_PATH = "music/atc_fadein.mp3";
    public static final String DRAG_START_SOUND_PATH = "music/atc_drag_start.mp3";
    public static final String DRAG_STOP_SOUND_PATH = "music/atc_drag_stop.mp3";

    public static final String FONT_REGULAR_PATH = "fonts/comfortaa_regular.ttf";
    public static final String FONT_LIGHT_PATH = "fonts/comfortaa_light.ttf";
    public static final String RUSSO_ONE_REGULAR = "fonts/russo_one_regular.ttf";

    public static TextureAtlas MAIN_ATLAS;

    public static I18NBundle LOCALE;

    /* MUSIC & SOUNDS */
    public static Music M3_THEME;
    public static Sound KICK_SOUND;
    public static Sound FADE_IN_SOUND;
    public static Sound DRAG_START_SOUND;
    public static Sound DRAG_STOP_SOUND;

    private Res () {
        MAIN_ATLAS = null;
    }

}
```

And my **ResManager**:

```
public class ResManager extends AssetManager {

    public void loadResources () {
        load(Res.MAIN_ATLAS_PATH, TextureAtlas.class);
        load(Res.MUSIC_M3_THEME_PATH, Music.class);
        load(Res.KICK_SOUND_PATH, Sound.class);
        load(Res.FADEIN_SOUND_PATH, Sound.class);
        load(Res.DRAG_START_SOUND_PATH, Sound.class);
        load(Res.DRAG_STOP_SOUND_PATH, Sound.class);
        load(Res.LOCALE_BUNDLE_PATH, I18NBundle.class);
        finishLoading();
        Res.MAIN_ATLAS = get(Res.MAIN_ATLAS_PATH, TextureAtlas.class);
        Res.M3_THEME = get(Res.MUSIC_M3_THEME_PATH, Music.class);
        Res.KICK_SOUND = get(Res.KICK_SOUND_PATH, Sound.class);
        Res.FADE_IN_SOUND = get(Res.FADEIN_SOUND_PATH, Sound.class);
        Res.DRAG_START_SOUND = get(Res.DRAG_START_SOUND_PATH, Sound.class);
        Res.DRAG_STOP_SOUND = get(Res.DRAG_STOP_SOUND_PATH, Sound.class);
        Res.LOCALE = get(Res.LOCALE_BUNDLE_PATH, I18NBundle.class);
    }

}
```

I know that in an Android ecosystem doing TextureAtlas static is a bad idea, but for the convenience of using resources in the code, it had to be done. In addition, it is still deleted from memory, because I kill the process while the application is shutting down.

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Also, I do the correct dispose of all screens, obviously pointing GC to unnecessary objects that he should has collected. For example:

```
@Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose(); // Stage
        loadingPane = null; // Group
        multiplexer = null; // InputMultiplexer
        firstScreen.destroy(); // Group
        secondScreen.destroy(); // Group
        firstScreen = null;
        secondScreen = null;
        bgSky = null; // Image
        ground = null; // Image
        dialogCircuit = null; // Group
        dialogModule = null; // Group
        dialogNotEnough = null; // Group
    }
```

Tried to catch memory leaks with the help of [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary). But it did not work. The log is empty.

Tell me, what could be the reason? A very annoying problem that kills all the joy of using my game.

**UPD:** Logcat logs (full): [logs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KpGNrDIvzG1KtAfLNuQFVWJodxlQblK2).
Game package name: *net.dailytoys.afterthecrash* (ironically, I understand)

Here are the logs that were the last ones before the crash, regarding this application (separated from the full log for convenience):

```
03-19 17:18:05.198 811-907/? W/InputDispatcher: channel 'ec9957f net.dailytoys.afterthecrash/net.dailytoys.afterthecrash.AndroidLauncher (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
03-19 17:18:05.198 811-907/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'ec9957f net.dailytoys.afterthecrash/net.dailytoys.afterthecrash.AndroidLauncher (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
03-19 17:18:05.213 811-1587/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{ec9957f u0 net.dailytoys.afterthecrash/net.dailytoys.afterthecrash.AndroidLauncher}
03-19 17:18:05.217 811-1587/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'ec9957f net.dailytoys.afterthecrash/net.dailytoys.afterthecrash.AndroidLauncher (server)'
03-19 17:18:05.223 811-1251/? I/ActivityManager: Process net.dailytoys.afterthecrash (pid 482) has died
03-19 17:18:05.257 811-1251/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{19f34039 u0 net.dailytoys.afterthecrash/.AndroidLauncher t3820}: app died, no saved state
03-19 17:18:05.258 811-1587/? W/WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{19cfd5d7 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{ec9957f u0 net.dailytoys.afterthecrash/net.dailytoys.afterthecrash.AndroidLauncher}
03-19 17:18:08.565 11009-11046/? D/IconCache: net.dailytoys.afterthecrash
03-19 17:18:08.566 11009-11046/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for net.dailytoys.afterthecrash: Resource ID #0x0
03-19 17:18:09.454 11009-11009/? D/IconCache: net.dailytoys.afterthecrash
03-19 17:18:09.456 11009-11009/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for net.dailytoys.afterthecrash: Resource ID #0x0
```

Comment: Did you check trace of your game from ADB? not game logs, from android logs?

Comment: @AbdullahTellioglu You meant to disable the filter in the logcat to view the logs of the system, and not just for a specific application? Now I'll do it, good idea.

Comment: Yes, Thats what I am saying and also you can save logs into a file using adb logcat > logcat.txt. I hope this helps too

Comment: @AbdullahTellioglu ok, I added an UPD to the post.

Comment: Double check that you're not filtering out your error messages. A game won't crash without any error messages...

Comment: @Tenfour04 I cleaned the filter and put the log into the post. Now I would like to be explained to me what to do with the error from the log: `Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

The problem was in very frequent `BitmapFont` generation. For each screen, several fonts were generated. I did this because the font size depends on the size of certain actors on these screens. I did not want to use scale for fonts, because it spoils the quality.

Even now, when I do `BitmapFont.dispose()`, all the same, too much memory is used, and leaks do not disappear. For this reason, I think that I need to reconsider my approach to programming the graphical user interface.

I think the best option would be to generate fonts of approximately the right size, and then scale them.